# panGestureRecognizer and Table Swipe

Tags: swift, uipangesturerecognizer, swrevealviewcontroller

I have a `UITableViewController` in Swift. This has a large table with the functionality to swipe and delete rows as necessary. This works fine when it's on its own.

I also have a sidebar function with the `SWRevealViewController` framework. As soon as I add the required `panGestureRecognizer` to the controller, then the table swipes don't work anymore.

I assume it's a conflict but I am not sure how to resolve it as the table swipe hasn't really been named in any way. I hope you can help?

EDIT

Current code:

```
func gestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer,
        shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer)
-> Bool {
            return true
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer,
        shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
            return true
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {



        // Create sidebar button
        sidebutton.addTarget(self.revealViewController(), action:"revealToggle:", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        // Add gestures for sidebar functionality
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer());

    }

// Handle deleting via row
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {


        // If they want to delete
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {

            //Delete method

            // Any errors? - KILL IT
            var error: NSError? = nil
            if !context.save(&error) {
                abort()
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the delegate for `panGestureRecognizer` to be your view controller and implement [`-gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:) in your view controller.

Returning `YES` should allow both to fire at the same time.

If not, then you might need to look at the delegate method [`-gestureRecognizer:shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:) and [`-gestureRecognizer:shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:) for more fine grain control.

---

After looking at `SWRevealViewController`, it look like they have their own delegate method.

`-revealController:panGestureRecognizerShouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` would be used instead of `-gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`

Comment: Hi Jeffery, I have added the code I currently have above to demonstrate the problem. I have tried two of the functions you have stated, but I don't know whether they are implemented correctly. They don't seem to be working as it is? I should also add, even without this they both fire but I have to REALLY struggle and hit the exact spot to get the delete button to show and on my phone it's almost impossible. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Jeffery. How would I write this in Swift? Having some trouble with it I assume this isn't correct `override func revealController(UIGestureRecognizer,
        panGestureRecognizerShouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
            
            return true
    }`

Comment: It's not an override because it's a delegate. The selector `- (BOOL)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController panGestureRecognizerShouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;` becomes `func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController,         panGestureRecognizerShouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer:UIGesture‌​Recognizer) -> Bool`.

Comment: As far as the implementation is concerned, you need to determine which gestures should work together.